# Change the path for ruby and irb to 1.9.2 in OSX

Tags: macos, path, ruby

I recently used [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install Ruby 1.9.2 on OSX. The binary for the new version seems to be in /usr/local/bin.

When I type "ruby" (or "irb") in a terminal, I want the binaries corresponding to 1.9.2 to be executed. At the moment I'm doing this with dirty aliases in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias 'ruby'=/usr/local/bin/ruby
alias 'gem'=/usr/local/bin/gem
alias 'irb'=/usr/local/bin/irb
```

Is there a better, more "correct" way to do this? I've heard people mention that I may need to fix my path?

Additionally, while the alias works for the 'ruby' and 'gem', it doesn't seem to work for the irb binary - when I type 'irb' it still loads a version of interactive ruby that can't handle syntax specific to ruby 1.9 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fix your PATH

Get rid of those aliases. Remove them from the `bash_profile`. First of all, check your path.

```
echo $PATH
```

Here, `/usr/local/bin` should take precedence over `/usr/bin`. If this isn't the case, something is wrong. Try if the following works, when you add this line to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Save it, open a new shell and run

```
which -a ruby
```

Now you should see that `/usr/local/bin/ruby` is used, whereas `/usr/bin/ruby` comes second (this is the default ruby 1.8.7 of OS X).

---

#### Alternative: Install RVM

For a better Ruby experience I would recommend you remove the Homebrew installation of Ruby altogether and [install RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), the Ruby Version Manager. Why? Because it allows you to switch between your locally installed Rubies and Gems.

Install `git` over Homebrew if you haven't already. Then:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

After the installation, add RVM to your `~/bash_profile` by entering the following into a terminal:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally, open a new Terminal window and check if RVM works:

```
type rvm | head -1
```

This should output "rvm is a function". You can then proceed to install Rubies:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

**Note:** For any further instruction type following in command line

```
rvm notes
```

This will give you comprehensive notes on what's and how's.

When this is done, you can set it as default:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

Comment: Thanks! The path method fixed it, but I think I'll follow your recommendation to use RVM.